# How to read version number from file name using shell script and regex

Tags: regex, shell, sed, windows-server-2008-r2, gnu-coreutils

I have a file in a folder that will be named something like version1.txt or version99.txt. I am on a Windows box that has GNU utilities installed and am doing this from command prompt. Currently, my output looks like this:

command: `dir | grep version`

result: `12/08/2016 04:50 PM                            0 version12.txt`

I want it to return the number 12 in this case.

I've written the regex which will match version12 (although I need it to match only 12), but I cannot figure out how to get it to be read with sed (I do not have awk available). This is what I am trying:

`dir | grep version | sed "/version[0-9]{2}|version[0-9]/g"`

How do I get only the version number to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` instead of `grep` to extract version number:

```
dir | awk '/version/{gsub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $NF); print $NF}'

12
```

---

You can use `sed` also:

```
dir | sed 's/.* version\|\..*//g'
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, I do not have awk available on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler alternative which removes the grep requirement:

```
dir /b version*.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```